# Density of Running Maximum of Drifted Brownian Motion Computation

Tags: calculus, integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> $\textbf{Proposition}$ The PDF of the Maximum of a Brownian Motion with Drift is given by
> $$
> f_{M_t}(m)={\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}} \exp\left( - \frac{(m-at)^2}{2t} \right) -2a\exp\left({2am}\right) \mathcal{N}\left ( \frac{-m-at}{\sqrt{t}} \right) 
> $$
> where $\mathcal{N}$ is the CDF of the standard normal variable.

Starting from the joint density of a drifted Brownian Motion $W_t$ and its running maximum $M_t=\sup_{s\le{t}}W_s$ I would like to compute the marginal density of $M_t$.

The joint density, which can be recovered through an application of Girsanov's theorem, reads

$$
f_{M_t,W_t}(m,\omega)=\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^2t}{2}+a\omega}\frac{2(2m-\omega)}{t \sqrt{2\pi t}}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(2m-\omega)^2}{2t}}}.
$$

Applying the Theorem of Tonelli-Fubini, together with the observation that  $M_t\le m \implies W_t\le m$, leads to the evaluation of

$$
f_{M_t}(m)=\int_{-\infty}^{m} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^2t}{2}+a\omega}\frac{2(2m-\omega)}{t \sqrt{2\pi t}}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(2m-\omega)^2}{2t}}}d\omega.
$$

Integrating by parts yields

$$ 
f_{M_t}(m)={\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}} \mathrm{e}^\frac{(m-at)^2}{2t}-\frac{2a}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^2t}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{m} \mathrm{e}^{a\omega}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(2m-\omega)^2}{2t}}}d\omega
$$

How do I solve this last integral?

Comment: Expand the square in the exponent under the last integral, collect the exponents, complete the square. You will arrive to the standard normal cdf (as claimed).

Comment: There is a sign type in the first term of the expression for the pdf. It should be $e^{-\frac{(m-at)^2}{2t}}$, otherwise the pdf is unbounded in $m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So continuing the computation gives:

\begin{align}
\frac{2a}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^2t}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{m} \mathrm{e}^{a\omega}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(2m-\omega)^2}{2t}}}d\omega &=\\
\frac{2a}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{m} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\omega-at)^2}{2t}}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-2m^2+\omega m}{t}}d\omega.
\end{align}

Now the change of variable $y=\frac{\omega-at}{\sqrt{t}}$ yields:

$$
2a\int_{-\infty}^\frac{m-at}{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}exp\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{4m^2-2mat+2m\sqrt{t}y}{2t} \right)dy
$$

Then

$$
2a\mathrm{e}^{2am}\int_{-\infty}^\frac{m-at}{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(y\sqrt{t}-2m)^2}{2t}} dy.
$$

A second change of variable $z=\frac{y\sqrt{t}-2m}{\sqrt{t}}$ finally gives

$$
2a\mathrm{e}^{2am}\int_{-\infty}^\frac{-m-at}{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp{\left( -\frac{z^2}{2}\right)} dz,
$$

and the term in the integral is the density $f_N (z)$ of a standard normal variable.